# ICS: how to get to browser home page?

Tags: browser, samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Newbie ICS question: how do I get back to my browser home page?

My Nexus S was OTA-upgraded yesterday to Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3 from 2.3 (Gingerbread), and I'm still finding my way around.

On Gingerbread's stock browser, I could hit the "search" button and it would show a list of frequently-visited sites. This wasn't exactly my home page but was close enough.

That list is gone in ICS, so I'm trying to figure out how to easily get to my browser home page without a lot of clicks. What's the trick?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to quickly view frequently visited pages, I would bookmark them and then add the "Bookmarks" widget to your homescreen. A few more steps involved, but pretty. And you don't even have to go into the browser to get to them!

[image: bookmarks widget]

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit the "windows" button in the upper-right, then the + button that appears to its left.

This creates a new window, however.

Answer (score 0):

Browser opens home page in every new tab by default.

Setting different home page in [Browser > Settings > General > Set homepage] and then just open new tab to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct "Home" key unfortunately.

As others have stated, you can open a new tab to display your "home page" - but you then might want to close your current tab - which is a 2nd tap.

Alternatively, if your home page is a standard web page then you could bookmark it as well. But this still requires 2 taps... one to display your bookmarks and another to action it.